# Initializer list in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I was reading about the initializer list and tried the code below on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>

class dog
{
    public:
    int age;
    dog(int a)
    {
        age = a;
        std::string name;
    }
    dog(const iterator_list<int>& vec)
    {
        age = *(vec.begin());
    }
};

int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

However it seems that it has a problem with the initializer list constructor

```
dog(const iterator_list<int>& vec)
{
    age = *(vec.begin());
}
```

Any suggestions ? Why it is having issues ?

Comment: Maybe you should try calling it **initializer_list** instead of **iterator_list**. And it belongs in the `std` namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `std::initializer_list` because, according to the docs, such object gets constructed by the compiler when:

- a braced-init-list is used to list-initialize an object, where the corresponding constructor accepts an `std::initializer_list` parameter
- a braced-init-list is used as the right operand of assignment or as a function call argument, and the corresponding assignment operator/function accepts an `std::initializer_list` parameter.

So you can have something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>

class dog
{
    public:
    int age;
    dog(int a)
    {
        age = a;
        std::string name;
    }
    dog(const initializer_list<int>& vec)
    {
        age = *(vec.begin());
    }
};
```

for constructing the class, you can use it like so:

```
dog d1( { 12, 16, 18, 20 } ); // if you will want more initialization data in the future
dog d2 = { 12 }; // or this, for now
```

and the value for `age` will be `12`

You always have to take care of the namespace your methods/classes belong to:

- use `std::initializer_list<int>`
- use `using namespace std;`

Also note that for selecting a constructor, default and `initializer_lists` constructors take precedence:

```
template<typename T>
struct Vector {
  Vector(const std::initializer_list<T> &values);
  Vector();
  Vector(const int size);
  Vector(const int size, const T& fill_with);
};

Vector<int> v1 {}; // empty list: the default constructor will be picked
Vector<int> v2 { 12 }; // the initializer_list constructor will be used
Vector<int> v3 (12); // Vector(const int) will be used
Vector<int> v4 (12, 0); // Vector(const int, const int&) will be used
```

Please check this out on [repl.it](https://repl.it/@victorbarbu/InitializerListConstructorsPrecedence).

Comment: `initializer_list` is easier to use compared to *what*?

Comment: It has to be called as 'dog d1 = {3};' since 'dog d1( 12, 16, 18, 20 );' returns an error.

Comment: I am terribly sorry for my mistake. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

It compiles with: `dog(const std::initializer_list<int>& vec)`